# Access ViewController from action in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have ViewController with TableView. In each cell of this TableView there are few buttons (so I can't use didSelectRow).

I need to get parent ViewController from action when buttons are pressed. So I add this function to my custom cell class:

```
@IBAction func editBtnPressed (_ sender: Any) {

}
```

I need to get to self in order to add some subviews to it.
How can I access root ViewController as **self**?

Comment: if you refer to **self ** in the button function, what class does it refer to? The  UITableView? Or the UITableViewCell?

Comment: I need to refer to UIViewController that has TableView that has Cell that has button with this action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you should do it by creating property of your controller in cell class and assign property value when after creating cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

For example:

in cell class

```
weak var yourController : YourViewController?
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.yourController = self
```

then you can access the `YourViewController` in `editBtnPressed` action.

But i suggest you to do by creating button action programmatically in your controller class. that's the good approach.

for example:

```
class YourCellClass: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOulet var myBtn: UIbutton!
  ...
}
```

Yourcontroller class

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! YourCellClass

    cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self. editBtnPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and in `editBtnPressed`

```
func editBtnPressed (_ sender: Any) {
 // you can access controller here by using self

}
```

Comment: Thanks for great solution !